# Swift2 access component with string-name

Tags: xcode, macos, swift2

Im more familiar with ActionScript3 and see many similarities in Swift2, kind of why i am trying out basic coding in Swift2 and Xcode.

Here's my example:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var b1CurrSpeed: NSTextField!
```

I want to store b1CurrSpeed as a string so i could access the actual textfield component to set its default value when application is loaded.

I'm aiming for Swift2 for osx apps.

Here is a fictional example, not related to any actual code:

```
var tf:NSTextField = this.getItem("b1CurrSpeed"); 
tf.stringValue = "Hello world";
```

Reason to this approach is following...
I would like to store textfield value in NSUserDefaults, the key for defaults would be name of that textfield. So when looping thru the defaults, i would like to get key as string and when ive got that i'd have access to actual component to set its stringvalue property.

Tho, is that good approach in Swift / xCode ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a function for it, do someting like this:

```
func getStringForKey(key: String) -> String {
    guard let result = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key) as! String else { return "" }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Even tho i still have to manually access the textfield, it will do for this simple test app :) thanks!

Comment: @schoeberlt Welcome to SO! Your answer above has received good feedback from the OP of this question, but generally avoid creating new answers, and simply edit your existing one instead. So for next time, use the "edit" option rather than new answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the TextFields value with `myTextField.text`

Comment: Please notify me if i am unclear in my question, what i want to do is the access b1CurrSpeed textfield with help of string. As a fictional example. var tf:NSTextField = this.getItem("b1CurrSpeed"); tf.stringValue = "Hello world";

Comment: Why do you want to access it with a string? If you made an outlet, you can refer to it everywhere, and use the punctuation syntax to access its properties/methods

Comment: I dont really have a decent answer to that question :P I think my coding-model is partially based on the way ive done it/similar things in AS3. This way might not be suitable for Swift2 / xCode i guess :/

Comment: Actually, i correct myself, i was thinking of having NSUserDefaults to store textfield contents, the key could be the textfield name. So looping thru defaults would give me textfield-name and what value it should contain. But is that a proper / good way to go for ?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know that language :D But in swift you can simply refer to it by calling the name of the outlet (or self.myTextField in closures, but Xcode will warn you if it is needed).

Comment: You don't have to loop throgh, you can get the value by myNewTextField.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("myTextField") as! String

Comment: that could work as simplest solution. Was tho kind of hoping to create a func where i can pass in name as string for getting the default and assigning it to specific textfield

Answer (score 0):

Swift's Mirror type can get you close to it but it is limited to NSObject subclasses, can only access stored properties and is read-only.

Yet, there are ways around these limitations if your requirements will allow.

For example, here's an extension that will save and restore defaults values for all UITextfields on a view controller using the name you gave to each IBOutlet.

```
 extension UIViewController
 {
    func loadDefaults(userDefaults: NSUserDefaults)
    {
        for prop in Mirror(reflecting:self).children
        {
           // add variants for each type/property you want to support 
           if let field = prop.value as? UITextField,  
              let name = prop.label
           {
              if let defaultValue = userDefaults.objectForKey(name) as? String 
              { field.text = defaultValue }          
           }          
        }
    }

    func saveDefaults(userDefaults: NSUserDefaults)
    {
        for prop in Mirror(reflecting:self).children
        {
           if let field = prop.value as? UITextField,
              let name = prop.label
           {
              if let currentValue = field.text
              { userDefaults.setObject(currentValue, forKey: name) }
           }          
        }
    }   
 }
```